# Image in full screen without bottom bar

Tags: android, android-image

iam developing one android application for Tablet, in which i need to show the image in full screen without bottom bar.How to do that?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: :have you got solution for this?i am also having same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean to do an effect like lights-out you can use this

```
yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

which will make every status bar button a single white dot, and when user touches one of them, they will be displayed to normal again

or you really want to disable it fully
you can make it in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

but what is the point for hiding **Back, Home, Recent** buttons ? It is against Android Design Guidelines, and how your user will quit the application in case of urgent exit like your application doesn't respond to touches?

Comment: Thanks for replay.It works fine.But is there any way to hide the dots of back button and  home button?For my application i dont want to allow the user to interact with application.Just iam want to show some videos and images at some schedule time and after playing the videos and images iam closing my application.

Comment: change the flag to this  yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION); or in your manifest add this <activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>

Comment: iam getting blank screen after one video play completed

Comment: it can be two possibilites;
1- your video has a blank part so actually video is being played but has a blank screen
2- your videoplayer is black since video is ended and there is no other video or anything else to show

Comment: iam using only VideoView not the media player, is that causing the issue?

Comment: no i mean video player in a general, not specifically `VideoPlayer` class, when you touch the screen it shows the video means, your device goes to sleep if you doesnt touch it for a while, so add this in your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`
and then in your code add this
`protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
mWakeLock.acquire();`

Comment: it says the error message  "Cannot make static reference to non static methon newWakeLock()"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33984/discussion-between-onur-a-and-joe)

Comment: i have used this code
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag"); 
wl.acquire();
But still screen is showing the black screen while playing the video, when i will touch the screen , the video will be shown.

Comment: when you touch it do you see any control buttons? like play/pause, stop, forward?

Comment: in my application,i dont need play, pause button controls,that's why Iam not using media player.

Comment: This code getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN); causes the blank screen after one video play completed.

Comment: at the same time , i don't need the bottom bar in the  tablet

Comment: i dont said to use thiscode getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);, i said this yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION); and i asked if yo usee anty control buttons, apparently you make the control manuel, you should make it auto

Comment: is there any other way to hide the bottom bar in my tablet

Comment: where should i need to put this code yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);   in the Oncreate() method?

Answer (score 2):

You can either do it in the onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

or in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to [use `setSystemUiVisibility()` on `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29) to attempt to control this, in particular with `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`. However, the effect is temporary -- the first screen touch will restore the navigation elements. This is so the user always has access to HOME, RECENTS, BACK, etc. on a tablet.

Comment: @joe: If you click the hyperlink in my answer, the JavaDocs contains sample code.